# Crontab not run as scheduled time

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Set this task in `crontab`, why didn't run every minute?

```
$ crontab -e

* * * * * cd /my/project/source/path && bundle exec rake publisher:publish --silent
```

But run this from terminal will work:

```
$ cd /my/project/source/path && bundle exec rake publisher:publish --silent
```

Comment: Beware of the `PATH` environment variable. Usually it is better to write the full path to the executable, in this case to `bundle`.

Comment: If it works in the terminal, but not in the crontab, it's usually a permission problem. For further investigation, you may take a look into the log: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. If you cannot see the cron log, you may explicitely add this in the crontab after your command: `>> /somewhere/the/crontab/user/can/write/to/log.txt 2>&1` that is: `* * * * * cd /my/project/source/path && bundle exec rake publisher:publish --silent >> /somewhere/the/crontab/user/can/write/to/log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:
/my/project/source/path/bundle exec rake publisher:publish --silent

Or:

"* * * * * * bash -c 'cd /my/project/source/path && bundle exec rake publisher:publish --silent'"

This way you pass the command as an argument to bash...

Comment: Thank you. But it not works.

Comment: Thanks for the info I fixed it.

Comment: `bash -c` also not work.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work?
the command is not executed or it does not execute as expected?

Is the Crontab user the same as the "Gemfile" owner you want to execute with "bundle exec rake"?

you can try passing the output to a textfile to get info why it fails.
"* * * * * * bash -c 'cd /my/project/source/path && bundle exec rake publisher:publish > logfile.txt' " 

also see "Yoirc" comment